# Python reading data file into lists or arrays

Tags: python, file-io

For some reason, I decided to save my list of data as a string.  If I use

```
f = open('tarfile.txt')
for line in f.readlines():
    print line
f.close()
```

my output looks like:

```
[  53.7775   13.4375   26.525    48.63    125.      185.      653.    ]    
[  53.7775    13.33625   26.73375   48.68375  125.       185.       653.     ]    
[  53.7775    13.325     27.11375   48.8875   126.       187.       653.     ]    
[  53.7775    13.43625   27.3175    48.92875  126.       187.       653.     ]    
[  53.7775    14.4825    33.07375   51.7325   141.       202.       595.     ]
```

I would like to read this data in to 2D array.  I have searched and tried various methods such as pickle, eval, json, etc but nothing worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `numpy` (or don't mind using it), you can do `numpy.loadtxt('tarfile.txt', usecols=range(1,8))`.  It is particularly nice if you are going to want your data in a 2-d `numpy` array anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Exactly what I needed.  Worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your input file contains floats separated by whitespace.

To read such a file, strip the `[` and `]`, split each line, and map each field to a float instance.

```
records = []
for line in f:
    record = [float(field) for field in line.strip().lstrip('[').rstrip(']').split()]
    records.append(record)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to translate the `[]` to something python can handle:

```
import string
table = string.maketrans('[]','  ')
```

Now you can iterate through your file, translating, splitting and floating:

```
for line in f:
    print [float(x) for x in line.translate(table).split()]
```

If you're guaranteed that `[` is the first character and `]` is the last character on the line, you can do it with slicing:

```
print [float(x) for x in line[1:-2].split()]  #-2 accounts for the newline too.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think regexp is the best way to parse your data:

```
import re
pattern = r'\d+.\d*'
array = []
for line in open('tarfile.txt'):
    array.append(re.findall(pattern, line))
```

Comment: This was clear and helpful and answered my array question as well.